# Models associations belongs to and has

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, associations

for the following how should be the models association

```
User can purchase many Items
Items can be purchased by many users
Items have many categories
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)  document seems to be self explanatory!

You need a [`has_many...through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship between `User` and `Item`, and a [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) relationship between `Item` and `Category`.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :items, through: :purchases
end

# app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :users, through: :purchases
  has_many :categories
end

# app/models/purchase.rb
class Purchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```